# What's the difference between Modernizr and Html5Shiv?

Tags: html5

I was toying with the idea of switching to html5. It seems there are 2 major scripts for dealing with supporting html5 on older browsers.

Modernizr and Html5Shiv

I was wondering if they do the same thing. Which one to choose and why?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modernizr is used to check the availability of HTML5 features in different rendering engines. It includes a script like Html5Shiv, which (only) enables HTML5 tags on Microsoft Internet Explorer (prior to version 9, which knew HTML5). See also ["How to get HTML5 working in IE and Firefox 2"](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/).

If you just want to enable HTML5 for IE < 9, then Html5Shiv would be sufficient. I'm using the [Html5Shiv version by Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) within a MS conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="templates/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

If you also want to check (via CSS or JS), if the clients browser is capable of e.g. [HTML5-form-elements](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html) (like Operas date input), CSS3 columns or gradients, then use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/).

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check out [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/), a good resource for starting with html5 sites, they provide toggleable choices like html5 shiv or modernizr along with many other baseline improvements.

Comment: yes html5boilerplate is good. It has a choice for modernizr or html5shiv. But which one to include?

Comment: fair enough, I guess html5 is what prompted the question?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is from a while back, but I felt I should add that modernizr doesn't appear to polyfill HTML5 elements that are loaded via AJAX - it only works on content that was present on initial page load.  Html5Shiv DOES work on content loaded via AJAX, but it's also only a small subset of modernizr's feature set.  We're actually using both on the web app I'm working on.